# Change session variables without reloading page

Tags: java, html, http, playframework, playframework-2.0

So my webpage has a Link `remove Advertisment` which should remove the ads from my website and remember to not show any ads in the rest of the session.

My approach at was first was a private static Variable in the controller, which could be set via methods.

```
private static boolean Ads = true;

public static void closeAds() {
    Logger.debug("Ads removed");
    Ads = false;
}
```

I did some research and found out that the `session()` method provided by the play framework probably would be more suitable.

Anyway my problem is, I don't know how to call those controller methods within my html page, since every HTTP request has to have an response and I don't want to reload my page, I only want to set the variable or session variable.

I figured Ajax could be the answer? I couldn`t come up with anything yet

Comment: Ajax is the way to go. But you'd still have to re-render the page after. The ads won't disapear magically. If you're using an MVC framework for the front-end, such as AngularJS, a simple ng-show/ng-hide around the ads would do the trick.

Comment: Use AJAX to update session information and JavaScript/DHTML to hide the ad on active page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play keeps session information on client side within a signed cookie.

So you have 2 options (I would go with the 2nd):

1) Ajax call to update play's session data (because you will not want to modify this on client side with javascript since it is a signed cookie and break things)

2) Create another cookie for keeping the advertisements on/off flag and modify it by javascript on clientside, and then you can check the value of this cookie on server side to achieve ads on/off. This will prevent you from doing an extra ajax call.